# SVN repository URL seems strange

Tags: svn

I was working at home and was trying to access an SVN repository at the office.
The URL I used to view the repository was:

```
https://dev.johnboy.com:58080/!/#engineering/
```

but what I had to use in Tortoise SVN for check out to work was:

```
https://dev.johnboy.com:58080/svn/engineering/
```

Here they are next to each other.

```
https://dev.johnboy.com:45080/!/#engineering/
https://dev.johnboy.com:45080/svn/engineering/
```

Could someone please explain. I haven't used SVN for 12 years (command line) but even so I don't remember anything like this.

Thanks,
JH

Comment: Anything after the hash isn't sent to the server, at the orign they are anchors to a div id into an html page, no js. But now many pages use it to alter or parse contents with just `location.hash` in js to retrieve values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of them is likely a web page that you view, using a client side Javascript framework (this is likely what the hashtag is for) that just serves a viewable copy - meant for browser consumption, while the second one is the "real" server-side URL that svn can interact with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I should have also asked how one would find the real URL in this case.

Comment: Virtually all of those web page viewers (for git, svn, whatever else) will have it somewhere. I don't think I've ever seen one that didn't have the raw URL _somewhere_ at all. I don't know what software is fronting the web interface.

Comment: It seems to be VisualSVN Server's web UI: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/. See the demo here: https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#raspberrypi-doc